# My app had been refused because of non-public APIs

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, appstore-approval, ios10

There is what Apple feedback：
Your app uses or references the following non-public APIs:

- “`init:`”

The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App Store because it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change.

what confused me most is that "init:",I mean really,what wrong with "init:"?We can not use "init:"?What's more,when we use non-public APIs is there any warming in Xcode?How can I find these non-public APIs?

Comment: I would appeal to Apple, or perhaps try again.  There seem to have been a lot of issue with non-public API with the release of iOS 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really shouldn't be using anything with the name `init:`. That would be an `init` method with one parameter, but no explanation about what that parameter is. For example:

```
- (instancetype) init:(NSString *)string;
```

That would always be an incorrect name. The correct name would be:

```
- (instancetype) initWithName:(NSString *)string;
```

(or `initWithTitle:` or `initWithSomeOtherThingButSomething:`)

So I would first search for `init:`, and that should be easily fixable. If you don't actually have any methods with that name, then this is possibly a bug in Apple's tool and you will need to discuss it with Apple.

Comment: I agree. I think the colon is a giveaway. I've had problems where I accidentally implemented a private method; it's easy to do by mistake because of the global namespace. But in any case there should not be any method called `init:`. You can call `init` with no parameter, or `initWithThing:` and a parameter, but not `init:`.

Comment: I search "init:" in my whole project then there shows two results:
- `id writer = [[_SBJsonWriterClass alloc]init:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Basic functions", @"Advanced functions", @"Accessory positioning", @"", nil]];`

- `id parser = [[_SBJSONParserClass alloc] init:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Basic functions", @"Advanced functions", @"Accessory positioning", @"", nil]];`
They are both in AFNetworking's AFJSONUtilities.m file.How can I solve this problem without delete AFNetworking?Just change the name?

Comment: Upgrade AFNetworking. That sounds like an ancient version (probably pre-1.0?). It's important to keep vendor libraries updated regularly.

Comment: Yeah,you are right. This is a very old project with some very old sdks,what's more,no cocoapod.I mean,if I want to upgrade AFNetworking,it's not so easy without cocoapod,what's more,there are many methods based on the old version AFNetworking in this project.Do you have a better solution?

Comment: You can try renaming things and see what happens, or talk to Apple. There's no answer in the general case to "what will Apple accept."

Comment: OK，I got what you said,thank you for your answer sincerely.